# Doing both INSERT and SELECT in same PHP file

Tags: php, mysql, json, web-services

In my webservice I have a page for inserting values of longitude and latitude. When successfully inserted into the database a new row is created in a table and with a key "id" (INT) which is auto increment.

It returns a JSON object:

> {"success":1,"message":"Spot Successfully Added!"}

My problem: I want to add the id that is created for each row to the resulting JSON object. Like this:

> {"success":1,"message":"Spot Successfully Added!","id":54}

This is what I've got so far. Rows are inserted into table, but I fail to display my id in the JSON Object:

> {"success":1,"message":"Spot Successfully Added!","like_id":null}

**idtest.php**

```
<?php
//load and connect to MySQL database stuff
require("config.inc.php");

if (!empty($_POST)) {


    //initial query
    if(isset($_POST['user_id']) && !empty($_POST['user_id'])) {
        $query = "INSERT INTO spot ( latitude, longitude, user_id ) VALUES ( :lat, :long, :uid ) ";
        //Update query
        $query_params = array(
            ':lat' => $_POST['latitude'],
            ':long' => $_POST['longitude'],
            ':uid' => $_POST['user_id']
            );

    } else {
        $query = "INSERT INTO spot ( latitude, longitude ) VALUES ( :lat, :long ) ";
        //Update query
        $query_params = array(
            ':lat' => $_POST['latitude'],
            ':long' => $_POST['longitude']
            );
    }
    //execute query
    try {
        $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
    }
    catch (PDOException $ex) {
        // For testing, you could use a die and message. 
        //die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());

        //or just use this use this one:
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Database Error. Couldn't add lat/long-pair!";
        die(json_encode($response));
    }

    $latt = $_POST['latitude'];
    $longg = $_POST['longitude'];

    $getId = "SELECT id FROM spot WHERE latitude=$latt AND longitude=$longg LIMIT 1";
    echo $getId;
    //execute query
    try {
        $stmt2   = $db->prepare($getId);
        $result2 = $stmt2->execute($query_params);
    }
    catch (PDOException $ex) {
        // For testing, you could use a die and message. 
        //die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());

        //or just use this use this one:
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Database Error. Couldn't retrieve like_id!";
        die(json_encode($response));
    }

    $row = $stmt2->fetchAll();
    if($row) {

    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "Spot Successfully Added!";
    $response["like_id"] = $row["id"];
    echo json_encode($response);
    }

} else {
    ?>
    <h1>Registrer GPS-koordinater</h1>
    <form action="idtest.php" method="post">
        Latitude:<br />
        <input type="text" name="latitude" value="" />
        <br /><br />
        Longitude:<br />
        <input type="text" name="longitude" value="" />
        <br /><br />
        Google ID:<br />
        <input type="text" name="user_id" value="" />
        <br /><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Opprett kolonne i 'spot'" />
    </form>
    <?php
}

?>
```

Comment: You needs quotes around `latitude='".$latt."' AND longitude='".$longg."'` OR it is better to use bind statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line

```
if($row) {
```

to

```
if(!$row) {
```

because $row is not find anywhere before that

Comment: You're right! Now I get {"success":1,"message":"Spot Successfully Added!","like_id":null}. Do you think there's a way to fix this? Could this be because the DB hasn't had time to generate ID through AUTO_INCREMENT?

Comment: i think you should use $row[0]['id']

Comment: Anyhow try to print_r($row) and check the array you get.

Comment: Thank you! Now it works perfectly it seems. I think I did not understand that $row is an array. I used $row[0]['id']